# Set cookies for form elements

Tags: javascript, forms, cookies

I'm trying to take values from a from and then and when it is submitted turn the values into a cookies. This is what I have, but I wanted to know if there was a way to make it so I didn't have to keep writing out the same thing for all of the variables.

```
function submitValues(){

var firstName = document.forms["frm1"]["first_name"].value;
var lastName  = document.forms["frm1"]["last_name"].value;
var number    = document.forms["frm1"]["phNum"].value;

setCookie("firstName",firstName,365);
setCookie("lastName",lastName,365);
setCookie("number",number,365);
}
```

Comment: I don't see how you are writing the same thing for all of the variables. The three variables would most likely have three distinct values. Where does the question of "same thing" arise?

Comment: I believe that he/she means that there are going to be more fields to which a cookie needs to be set with a value rather than the firstName, lastName, and number. So the question seems to be "Is there a way to loop through all of the form fields and create a cookie with the corresponding value for each field in the form?" Without having to declare each of the values as a variable as they have written above.

Comment: Yes, sbeliv01 was right, I didn't do a good job of asking the question. Is there a way that I would be able to do it with parameters? When I have something like `["frm1"]["first_name"].value;` and have parameters inside the quotations it doesn't work.

Comment: @user1290426 See the edit to my question regarding how to use parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set cookies for all form elements, use the [DOM2 `form.elements` collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/form.elements):

```
var els = document.forms.frm1.elements;
for (var i=els.length;i--;){
  setCookie(els[i].name, els[i].value, 365);
}
```

If you want only specific, then write your code like so:

```
var els = document.forms.frm1.elements;
var cookiesToSet = ['first_name','last_name','phNum'];
for (var i=cookiesToSet.length;i--;){
  var name = cookiesToSet[i];
  setCookie(name, els[name].value, 365);
}
```

In the above, `els[name]` is equivalent to `document.forms.frm1.elements[name]`.

In general, every property of every object in JavaScript is accessible via either "dot notation" (`foo.bar`) or "bracket notation" (`foo["bar"]`). You must use the latter when the property name is not a valid identifier(`foo["names[]"]` or `foo["12 freakin' whales!"]`) or when constructing the property name from a variable (`foo[name]` or `foo["item"+i]`).

Answer (score 2):

You could shorten it somewhat by saving a reference to the form in a variable, like so:

```
var form = document.forms["frm1"];

var firstName = form["first_name"].value;
//...and so on
```

Or to shorten it even more by looping through all the `<input>` elements in the form:

```
var formInputs = document.forms["frm1"].getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i=0;i<formInputs.length;i++) {
    setCookie(formInputs[i].name, formInputs[i].value, 365);
}
```